# move_uploaded_file() can't open stream

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload files via Pycurl through POST, using a PHP script on the receiving end. For some reason the PHP part seems to cause an error. I've distilled it down to two short test scripts.

```
import pycurl

UPLOADURL = "http://127.0.0.1/~nevon/receive.php" #URL to the PHP script
PATH = "/home/nevon/Desktop/testfile" #path to the file I'm trying to upload

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL, UPLOADURL)
c.setopt( c.HTTPPOST, [("uploaded", (c.FORM_FILE, PATH))] )
c.perform()
c.close()
```

receive.php:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$target = getcwd()."/upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; $ok=1; 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } else { 
    echo "Something went wrong."; 
    } 
?>
```

The errors I'm receiving when testing this are:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/nevon/public_html/upload/testfile): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nevon/public_html/receive.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpevKFCC' to '/home/nevon/public_html/upload/testfile' in /home/nevon/public_html/receive.php on line 7
```

It doesn't seem like a permissions problem, but nevertheless I've checked the permissions of both the uploading directory and /tmp. I've also checked so that it isn't a problem with open_basedir restriction.

In the PHP manual on move_uploaded_file() it says the following:

> move_uploaded_file() ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be moved.

Since I'm uploading via Python with Curl, I figured that might be the problem. But isn't there supposed to be a different error message if that was the case? *If that is indeed the problem, what could I do instead?* I haven't really used PHP much for years now, so you could say I'm a little rusty.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but just in case, I'm testing this on Ubuntu 10.10 with apache 2.2.16, PHP 5.3.3 and Python 2.6.6.

EDIT: The plot thickens! A person on Twitter took my PHP script and put it on his server, to see if he could find out what the problem was. It worked fine for him, when uploading via a regular PHP/HTML form. So I pointed my Python script to his PHP script, and all of a sudden it worked just fine. So now I'm wondering, what's wrong on my end...? How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: DID YU ACCES THE FILE DIRECTLY BY TYPING THE PATH? DESTINATION FOLDER ALSO HAVE THE PERMISSION ?

Comment: Yes and yes. The file (that I'm trying to upload) is fully accessible. The destination folder has been set to chmod 777.

Comment: move_uploaded_file should return false if the file you're trying to move wasn't a file upload. So I don't think it has anything to do with how you're uploading file, be it from a post form, or from pycurl. Also try checking $_FILES['uploaded']['error'] just in case.

Comment: Step one should be `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: I checked $_FILES['uploaded']['error']. It only contained 0, which I assume means "no error". move_uploaded_file does return false, but only on my machine (and my web host). As I said in the update to my post, it works on someone else's host.

Comment: @meagar: var_dump($_FILES) returns:
    array(1) {
        ["uploaded"]=>
        array(5) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(8) "testfile"
            ["type"]=>
            string(24) "application/octet-stream"
            ["tmp_name"]=>
            string(14) "/tmp/phpkCnZas"
            ["error"]=>
            int(0)
            ["size"]=>
            int(0)
        }
    }

EDIT: Sorry about the mess. Check here (http://pastie.org/1239233) for a more readable printout.

Comment: Your script looks in order. It is clearly a problem with `$target`. Are you 10000% sure that the directory `/upload` already exists? Note that `move_uploaded_file()` can't create that for you.

Comment: @Pekka: Yes. I am 1000000% sure that /upload exists and is writable.

Comment: @Tommy really strange. There doesn't happen to be a file named `testfile` in the directory? What if you try some other, random file name for `$target`?

Comment: @Pekka: /upload is completely empty. Even if there already was a file named testfile in there, it would be overwritten - according to the php manual. I also tried setting the destination to something different. No change.

Comment: @Tommy really strange. Then I'm out of ideas, interested to see what this turns out to have been!

Comment: Wow. This is embarrassing. I just spent the last 3-4 hours debugging this, only to now see that I did indeed make a typo. The directory was called "upload", whereas I was trying to move the files to "uploads".

Comment: @Tommy ahahaha! Well, that happens to the best of us. Good that it got sorted. :)

Comment: I'm adding my comment from above as an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script looks in order. It is clearly a problem with the `$target` directory. Make 10000% sure that the directory /upload already exists. `move_uploaded_file()` can't create it for you.