# using copy() and move_uploaded_file() error message: failed to open stream - php

Tags: php

I am using `copy` and `move_uploaded_file()` copy(/tmp/phpJ0lg4r.jpeg) [function.copy]:  it gives me the error **failed to open stream: No such file or directory in**

I do not think there is an error in the code, but its the image temp path somewhere the error.

Any ideas to why?

--EDIT--

1. The file permission is :777
2. Using only move_uploaded_file

---CODE--

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">  
        <INPUT NAME="u" TYPE="file" size="90">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['u'.$i]['name'],"Path_Of_Directory");
```

Though there are several checks of the type of file, this is the basic.  It just does not copy or move the file.

Comment: Copy **and** move_uploaded_file? You should be using just one at the time (move_uploaded_file).

Comment: Post some code please. Most likely the image path is incorrect, but it's hard to tell anything without code.

Comment: Check if the file exists in the directory exists.

Comment: Are file and directory permissions ok

Comment: The image path is incorrect, print it out to make sure it's the path you want. And please give us some code...

Comment: @HansWassink code is added.  I did not put in the code, because the there was an error in the tmp/ path.

Comment: `$HTTP_POST_FILES['u'.$i]['name']` is deprecated, you should be using the `$_FILES` array. Also, the `'u'.$i` index doesn't seem to exist, as your form only has input name `'u'`.

Comment: @HansWassink those are part of the code, now that is not important.  What is important is why an error is appearing.  As of now I got why the error is appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["u"]["tmp_name"], "Path_Of_Directory");`

Comment: you need to use `tmp_name` instead of `name` in array index.

Comment: This is rather confusing..no error message, but not copied hmm

Comment: from the stub of the error message he posted, it's tmp file he is trying to copy. However, nothing can be trusted with such a way of asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such file or directory, either source or destination one.

Sincerely yours, colonel Obvious.

Hint: an error message contains detailed explanation, pointing exactly to the point where expected file or directory is missing. It always makes me wonder, why nobody ever bother to read it nor at least post it's exact copy in their question to let others read and tell you where is the problem.

Let's take a look at [the properly asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991931/move-uploaded-file-cant-open-stream):

It contains error messages telling us the the problem apparently in the destination directory. (from the second one we can tell that `/home/nevon/...` is a destination and first one says there is no such file).
Armed with such knowledge, you have to just verify the destination path.
Unlike *guessing*, certain knowledge is WAY more efficient.

Programming is **exact science**. One have to investigate, to make use of feedback, to analyze. Not to guess.

Comment: Col, Well it is obvious the error is it cannot find the tmp directory, now what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: It is not obvious *to the reader*. There are **two** directories takes part in the process. anyway, if it's temp directory - what is the path system looking for? Why don't you examine that path yourself? Why don't you post it here to let people help you?

Comment: Edited the question to provide the path that is not found.  Now could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Not your code nor error message looks like exact ones. Sorry buddy, it's impossible to help someone who is not interested in the getting help at all.

Comment: I think you got me wrong.  It was more of the /tmp path not found.  That is certainly not an error in my code.  It would be a variable pass or something, which @gurav has stated clearly.  Thank you for writing in.

Comment: "variable pass" is certainly part of "your code". It seems you're looking for something to blame on, not the solution :)))